# Need help with AMPscript code

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

can someone help me to write a code that will retrieve a salesforce object. 
The name of the field in SF is: Preferred Contact Time 
The name of the field in MC synced is: Preferred_Contact_Time_Pez__c

This field exists in the lead in SF. Once i get the code, i will put in HTML in an email. Thanks

Im new to AMPSCRIPT and programming in general. Here is the last one i tried,

```
%%[
    VAR@PreferredContactTime
    SET@PreferredContactTime=RetrieveSalesforceObjects(“Lead”,”FirstName,LastName,Email”,”Id”,”=”,_Subscriberkey) 
    If RowCount(@PreferredContactTime)==1 
        then 
            VAR@PreferredContactTime,@FirstName 
            SET@PreferredContactTime=Row(@PreferredContactTime,1) 
    Endif 
]%%
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Im new to AMPSCRIPT and programming in general. Here is the last one i tried,      <!--%%[
VAR@PreferredContactTime
SET@PreferredContactTime=RetrieveSalesforceObjects(“Lead”,”FirstName,LastName,Email”,”Id”,”=”,_Subscriberkey) 
If RowCount(@PreferredContactTime)==1 then 
VAR@PreferredContactTime,@FirstName 
SET@PreferredContactTime=Row(@PreferredContactTime,1) 
Endif 
]%%

Comment: Comment length and formatting options are limited. You should add that to your question by making an [edit].

Comment: I added it to the first comment but its not showing so i don't know. You cannot see it in my last comment ?

Comment: That's because you started an html comment `<!--`. When providing code and/or markup (like html) it helps if you tell SFSE to format that text as a block of code. The `{}` button in the rich text editor formats a highlighted section of text as a code block (`ctrl` + `k`, `cmd` + `k` on mac, does the same thing)

Comment: Yes, I could see it in the comment, but comments are not the place to add additional information to your question. Comments are best thought of as temporary, and code being jammed into a comment is hard to read (and harder to debug).

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

Assuming Preferred Contact time API as "Preferred_Contact_time__c"

```
 %%[

var @PreferredContactTime

set @PreferredContactTime = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Lead",
   "Id, FirstName,LastName,Email, Preferred_Contact_time__c",
   "Id", "=", @Id)

if RowCount(@PreferredContactTime) == 1 then
  var @subscriberRow, @firstName, @lastName, @email, @Preferredname
  set @subscriberRow = Row(@PreferredContactTime, 1)
  set @firstName = Field(@subscriberRow, "FirstName")
  set @lastName = Field(@subscriberRow, "LastName")
  set @email = Field(@subscriberRow, "Email")
  set @Preferredname = Field(@subscriberRow, "Preferred_Contact_time__c")
endif

]%%
```

Comment: i just tried it, it didn't work

Comment: Can you let me know Whether you are using email or ID as subscriberkey

Comment: Normally i use Lead ID in the entry source of the journey. Because i need to put this code in an email in a journey

Comment: I edited the code try once, if not working i will check on that

Comment: it didn't work. I populate that field in the email like this: %%=v(@PreferredContactTime)=%% , but it's blank which means the code didn't work ,   My Preferred Contact time API is "Preferred_Contact_Time_Pez__c"  and it did put it in the codeyou sent me this way

Comment: You should put %%=v(@Preferredname)=%% in the email not %%=v(@PreferredContactTime)=%%.

Comment: I just did. Didn't work. I give up